# WFS Query Failing when using Logical OR

Tags: geoserver, wfs, xml

I'm having some difficulty when using a Logical `OR` in a WFS query to get multiple postcodes. This code works fine when it's only 1 `PropertyIsEqualTo` filter, but when I wrap the OR around more than one `PropertyIsEqualTo` filter I get an exception.

```
POST http://intranet.nottscc.gov.uk/maps/wfs HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: text/xml
Host: intranet.nottscc.gov.uk
Content-Length: 1875
Expect: 100-continue

<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ncc="http://nottinghamshire.gov.uk" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<wfs:Query typeName="ncc:OSCodepoint_15KM">
<wfs:PropertyName>ncc:FORMAT1</wfs:PropertyName>
<wfs:PropertyName>ncc:EASTING</wfs:PropertyName>
<wfs:PropertyName>ncc:NORTHING</wfs:PropertyName>
<ogc:Filter>
  <ogc:OR>
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyName>ncc:FORMAT3</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>NG156LR</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyName>ncc:FORMAT3</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>NG163GP</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyName>ncc:FORMAT3</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>NG158AY</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyName>ncc:FORMAT3</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>NG171ER</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:OR>
    </ogc:Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

This is the Error message I get.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://intranet.nottscc.gov.uk/maps/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>Error occurred getting features Invalid fid filter provides, has no fids inside Invalid fid filter provides, has no fids inside</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

I'm using GeoServer to process the query.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a capitalized `Or` instead of all-caps `OR` to wrap your criteria:

```
<ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:Or>
        <!-- Criteria -->
    </ogc:Or>
</ogc:Filter>
```

I can't find any definitive answers about case sensitivity in filters, but the XML schema on the OGC site uses "Or" instead of "OR".

Comment: Thanks very much, my hair is still intact. The mistake was using Mapserver for the examples http://mapserver.org/ogc/filter_encoding.html where they use CAPITALS and then implementing it with GeoServer where they don't.

Comment: XML is case sensitive and it should be Or