# And/or query on WFS service?

Tags: wfs, open-source-gis

Is it possible to use "and" & "or" queries on a WFS service through the URL?

Here's my current URL:

```
http://mywebsite.com/county_roads_wms_only/MapServer/WFSServer?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typename=county_roads_wms_only:Roads&maxfeatures=2&filter=<ogc:Filter><ogc:PropertyIsLike escape="\" singleChar="_" wildCard="%"><ogc:PropertyName>Road_Label</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>%mcculloch%</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsLike></ogc:Filter>'
```

Is there a way to form it so that it would be "%mcculloch% AND %st%" or "%mcculloch% OR %st% in the URL?

Comment: Does `%20AND%20` work (between the variables)?

Comment: It doesn't. This works:http://mymapservice.com/...&filter=<ogc:Filter><ogc:Or><ogc:PropertyIsLike%20escape="\"%20singleChar="_"%20wildCard="%"><ogc:PropertyName>Road_Label</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>%harmony%</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsLike><ogc:PropertyIsLike%20escape="\"%20singleChar="_"%20wildCard="%"><ogc:PropertyName>Road_Label</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>%blvd%</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsLike></ogc:Or></ogc:Filter>. I found a related question here that helped solve the issue:http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18473/wfs-query-failing-when-using-logical-or

Comment: Great! I was totally just guessing.

Comment: OGC standards are not an enjoy to read but they are often better than guessing. In this case the answer is in Filter Encoding Standard 1.1.0 https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=51130.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
http://mymapservice.com/?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typename=county_roads_wms_only:Roads&filter=<ogc:Filter><ogc:Or><ogc:PropertyIsLike escape="\" singleChar="_" wildCard="%"><ogc:PropertyName>Road_Label</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>%harmony%</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsLike><ogc:PropertyIsLike escape="\" singleChar="_" wildCard="%"><ogc:PropertyName>Road_Label</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>%blvd%</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsLike></ogc:Or></ogc:Filter>
```

The or operator is  and goes directly after the  tag. Then you just repeat the  or whatever parameter with a different  tag value for each or in your query.